# TypeError: Cannot clone object '<>' (type <class ''>): it does not seem to be a scikit-learn estimator as it does not implement a 'get_params' methods

Tags: python, keras, scikit-learn, ensemble-learning

**I want to use votingClassifier or EnsembleVoteClassifier voting method with 3 different models but I have this error
I need your help to solve this problem!**

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mlxtend.classifier import EnsembleVoteClassifier
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions

# Initializing Classifiers
clf1 = modelvgg16
clf2 = AlexNetModel
clf3 = InceptionV3Model
for model in [clf1, clf2,clf3]:
    model._estimator_type = "classifier"
    #print(model._estimator_type)
eclf = EnsembleVoteClassifier(clfs=[clf1, clf2,clf3],weights=[2, 1, 1], voting='soft')

X, Y = training_set.next()    
Y=np.zeros(X.shape[0]) # number of calsses is 38 
print("X.shape =",X.shape) # X.shape = (128, 224, 224, 3)
print("Y.shape =",Y.shape) # Y.shape = (38,)

######################### Split train+test #######################################
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = 0.20,random_state=2)
# Whole Wine Classifier
ensemble_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = ensemble_model.predict(x_test)
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print("accueacy : ",accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred))
```

for more information see my project on this link:
[my project](https://www.kaggle.com/boulaalamcfk/try-votingclassifiser-and-ensemblevoteclassifier?scriptVersionId=42904213)

I got the same error when running this code:

[image]